# YouTube API refresh token flow

Tags: asp.net-web-api, youtube, youtube-api, google-authentication

I am building an ASP.NET Web API. I am using YouTube API to upload videos on YouTube. I have managed to implement the OAuth with refresh token flow. After generating a refresh token I am using the following code for all the subsequent calls to YouTube API.

```
var token = new TokenResponse { RefreshToken = REFRESH_TOKEN };
var credentials = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
    {
        ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets { ClientId = CLIENT_ID, ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET }
    }), "user", token);

YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService((new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credentials
}));
```

I want to know **when this refresh token will expire and how I would regenerate this refresh token without any user input/interaction** so that end user does not see a Google account selection screen (in my case I see two accounts, a gmail one and a YouTube channel's one).

Also, if I have one refresh token generated, then I do not get a refresh token in response if I try to initiate the OAuth process again by using `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth` again. Can I only have one refresh token at a time?

Answer (score 0):

There are examples, also in the documentation and other similar questions here. However, maybe not in your programming language.
The refreshToken should be saved by you and reused. It is valid until it gets revoked by the user himself. Getting a refreshToken requiers user interaction. 
Once you have obtained the refreshToken use it in another request to obtain an accessToken. The accessToken is needed in YouTube API requests for some data access. An accesToken expires after 1 hour (3600 seconds), although this period could be changed in the future.